# MySQL hook up to a website?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a WebSite for my Church.  I don't have much experience in IT, but I have a home page with html and css right now.  I would like to have a database that I could hook it up to.. Are there any basic tutorials on how to do this?  I am running linux mint.  and My website is PHP.

How could i hook up a MySQL Database to the website.  THanks for your help!

Comment: The ones I have looked at are good, for instance i downloaded XAMPP and made a database, but i don't know how to make calls to the database from my websitte.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. It's very appropriate for beginners: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Good luck :)

Comment: This answer is definitely a good one.  I learned PHP and MySQL the hard way by essentially reverse engineering an OSCommerce site.  A w3schools.com tutorial would have been much more appropriate.

Comment: Brad, I feel for you. That was herculean. :D

Answer (score 1):

use [PHP's MySQL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) to access your database.  Scroll down to the comments and you'll see a number of examples of common uses.

Answer (score 0):

> How could i hook up a MySQL Database to the website. THanks for your help!

Your **website hosting provider** may already provide you with MySQL databases.. check your **admin control panel** to see what you have.
-- If you can't figure this out, **contact your hosting provider**.

When you've made it past that point, just find and follow one of the basic database creation tutorials out there.